# algebra tikz with arrows for algebra (functions and sets)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

How can this be drawn with tikz package?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight forward solution you can start with. For future questions [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) are always appreciated.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzset{
    arrow/.style = {-stealth},
}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \node (Z) at (0,2) {z};
        \node (Y) at (0,0) {y};
        \node (X) at (0,-2) {x};
        

        \node (A) at (3,4) {a};
        \node (B) at (3,2) {b};
        \node (C) at (3,-1) {c};
        \node (D) at (3,-2) {d};
        \node (E) at (3,-3) {e};
        \node (F) at (3,-4) {f};
        
        \path[arrow]
        (A) edge[bend right] (Z);       
        \path[arrow]
        (Z) edge[bend right] (A);
        
        \path[arrow]
        (B) edge[bend right] (Y);       
        \path[arrow]
        (Y) edge[bend right] (B);
        \path[arrow]
        (X) edge[bend right] (C);       
        \path[arrow]
        (C) edge[bend right] (X);
        \path[arrow]
        (D) edge[bend left] (X);
        \path[arrow]
        (E) edge[bend left] (X);
        \path[arrow]
        (F) edge[bend left] (X);
        
        %ellipse
        \draw (0,0) ellipse (1cm and 3cm) node[above, yshift=3cm] {x};
        \draw (3,0) ellipse (1.5cm and 5cm) node[above, yshift=5cm] {y};
            
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]